# CSS border gradient extend to other div

Tags: html, css, sass, border

I want to have this kind of output below. I seem cannot find any sources on how to do it. I only found this kind of code below but is not extending its color to other divs

```
.border-gradient {
  border: 10px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #743ad5, #d53a9d);
}
```

[image]

Comment: So you are looking for the gradient effect to go across the border of multiple elements, yes?

Comment: You may want to try using psuedo elements for your border and a some kind of clip to a gradient below?

Comment: yes, it would be better if I have a gradient in the div and the children border and text will use those as their color